# Update properties file values with form values

Tags: java

I am having a jsp file in which I load the existing values present in properties file. When the user edit the existing value and submit the form, the properties file must be updated with that values. Can anyone help me with this? I am using only java.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("Example.properties");
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(in);
```

Now Update it

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("Example.properties");
props.setProperty("valueTobeUpdate", "new Value");
props.store(outputStream , null);
outputStream .close();
```

Another way of achieving same is explained at

http://crunchify.com/java-properties-files-how-to-update-config-properties-file-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of how to update your properties file :

```
public class PropertyManager {
    private static Properties prop = new Properties();
    private static String PROPERTY_FILENAME = "config.properties";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        loadProperty();
        System.out.println(prop.get("myProperty"));
        updateProperty("myProperty", "aSecondValue");
    }

    public static void loadProperty(){

        InputStream input = null;

        try {

            input = new FileInputStream(PROPERTY_FILENAME);
            // load a properties file
            prop.load(input);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void updateProperty(String name, String value){
        OutputStream output = null;

        try {

            output = new FileOutputStream(PROPERTY_FILENAME);

            // set the properties value
            prop.setProperty(name, value);

            // save properties to project root folder
            prop.store(output, null);

        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (output != null) {
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I let you change "new Properties", by the way you retrieve it.

Comment: i edited my answer to write a complete example, and the file is correctly updated. Hope this help

Comment: The code is working fine.But the changes are getting stored in a new properties file inside the project. But I want the changes to be reflected in the existing properties file which is inside the src folder

Answer (score 0):

```
PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("/Users/abc/Documents/config.properties");
        config.setProperty("Name", "abcd");
        config.setProperty("Email", "abcd@gmail.com");
        config.setProperty("Phone", "123456");
        config.save();
```